# Regioselectivity for electrophilic aromatic substitution with multiple strongly electron withdrawing groups

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds

> At which position will electrophilic substitution on *p*-cyanonitrobenzene occur?

As both are -M groups, there are two possible sites of reaction, *meta* to each of the groups.
The answer is *meta* to $\ce{CN-}$. Why is this so? According to me it should be *meta* to $\ce{NO2}$, because $\ce{NO2}$ is the stronger -M group?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE. Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. This appears to be a [homework question](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/), please share your thoughts and attempts towards the solution. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you.

Comment: For such compound most eletrophilic  subst. wouldn't work

Answer (score 3):

As Mithoron suggests, the correct answer is probably "no reaction." There are no examples of electrophilic aromatic substitution of *p*-cyanonitrobenzene in SciFinder, by the introductory organic chemistry mechanism at least.

There is one report of halogenation (with *N*-halosuccinimide) of this compound with palladium catalysis. The cyano group serves as a directing group to place a halogen *ortho* to the cyano. Chlorination and bromination are both reported.

Reference: [Palladium-Catalyzed Highly Selective ortho-Halogenation (I, Br, Cl) of Arylnitriles via sp2 C–H Bond Activation Using Cyano as Directing Group](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo302765g)

Comment: Do you mean that there is no such reaction at all ?

Comment: @arutoregni using the typical conditions. For example, reaction of p-cyanonitrobenzene with bromine and iron tribromide has never been reported in the literature. Halogenation has been accomplished by a different mechanism, which is what is described in the answer.